# How can I tell prettier to parse files recursively?

Tags: javascript, prettier

I'd like to ask [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) to parse my JavaScript files recursively instead of specifying each folder in which it should check the files.

I'd like to do something like:

`prettier --write "all_js_files_except_node_modules_folder"`

I don't find much into their documentation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1358) from a few weeks back seems like it answers your question. TL;DR:

```
prettier "{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.js"
```

Answer (score 21):

Just run `prettier --write .`

And use a `.prettierignore` file to tell it what to ignore, but it ignores `node_modules` by default.

Answer (score 8):

If you're like me, you didn't recognize that the target files used globs format.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob). (Check the explanation about special chars). If you want to learn much more check here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

My folder structure:

```
components/
pages/
node_modules/
package.json    
server.js
```

I want to ignore `package.json` and `node_modules/`. I solved my needs with this command:

```
prettier --write "{*.js,!(node*)**/*.js}"`
```

The `{}` is an expansion mechanism which allows me to use several filter criteria. In my case there were 2:

1: `*.js`: target all JS files in the root where the command is executed

2: `!(node*)**/*.js`: target all the JS files in all the folders and subfolders (the recursive part is obtained by using the `**`)

Comment: @Pete [says it ignores `node_modules` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65635301/1028230). Was that accurate?

Comment: Found [docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#ignoring-files-prettierignore). Looks like it should be ignored. "_By default prettier ignores files in version control systems directories (".git", ".svn" and ".hg") and node_modules (if --with-node-modules CLI option not specified)_" ✔

Answer (score 7):

#### How to run recursively (*answering the question's title*)

For cut & pasters who came here for a straightforward example (no brackets, `or`s, etc) that answers the question in the title, the following could be a useful globs example:

`prettier --write "app/**/*.ts"`

That command recursively runs prettier for all `*.ts` files under the `app` directory.

---

#### How to ignore folders [while running recursively] (*answering the question's details*)

As נשמה קשוחה ([tough soul](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%97%D7%94&op=translate)?) has [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65635301/1028230), from the command line [prettier already ignores `node_modules` folders](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html#file-patterns):

> Prettier CLI will ignore files located in `node_modules` directory. To opt out from this behavior, use `--with-node-modules` flag.

If you wanted to ignore another folder, soul again has the [right idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65635301/1028230) by suggesting [a .prettierignore file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html), which will be used by the CLI.

Include...

```
**/folderToIgnore
```

... in your `.prettierignore` (*note leading `.` in `.prettierignore`!!!*) file to ignore **EVERY** folder with the name `folderToIgnore`, regardless of path.

As long as `.prettierignore` is in the same folder *or upstream* from your files' path, you should be good, though look out for interactions if you have multiple `.prettierignore`s.

Answer (score 3):

The issue for me was that I had to add quotes

somewhere in your package.json

`"format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\""`

Comment: For me this solution worked, but you could have used single quotes so you don't have to escape them.

Comment: maybe you are right

Answer (score 2):

Adding as npm script did the trick for me:

- **package.json** defined npm script

It will recursively fix following files.**ext** with the following set of rules defined in `prettierrc` file.

Important: .<EXTENSION || MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS> e.g'./src/**/*.{js,jsx,scss,md,json}' (Include all files and folders)

- Don't miss the **quotes** -> **'** PATH>.<EXTENSION || MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS> **'**

```json
{
    "name": "compentence-journey",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
    "prettier.fix": "prettier --check --write './src/**/*.{js,jsx,scss,md,json}'",
    },
   ...

}
```

- **.prettierrc** JSON file

```json
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

- **.prettierignore** ignore folder/files from formatting

```json
/config

# Dependency directories
node_modules/

# Publish Directory
build/

# Root level folders/files
/package.json
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works best for me. It's the only method I've found that will hit every file regardless of how nested it is:

`package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write {,*/**/}*.{js,jsx,json}",
  },
```

`.prettierignore`

```
node_modules
build
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the extended glob to work recursively in the `package.json` file, you need extra quotes.

```json
....
"scripts": {
    ....
    "format": "prettier './**/*.ts' --write --ignore-path ./.gitignore"
},
```